# System.IdentityModel.Metadata and X509SecurityToken not available in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, active-directory

I'm currently trying to get signing keys from Azure Active Directory based on the [signing key rollover guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-signing-key-rollover) over at Microsoft docs in order to authenticate HTTP requests on an ASP.NET Core Web API endpoint I'm developing.

Although I migrated the source code shown in the article it doesn't seem like some references and classes are available in ASP.NET Core web apps such as `System.IdentityModel.Metadata` and classes like `X509SecurityToken`, `MetadataSerializer`, `EntityDescriptor` and `X509RawDataKeyIdentifierClause`.

[Source code with types not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9h5f.jpg)

I already searched on NuGet, but it doesn't seem like packages are available for System.IdentityModel and I'm not able to reference system assemblies in ASP.NET Core neither.

Which libraries shall I use in ASP.NET Core instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to handles key rollover manually in a ASP.Net core if you using the .NET Core OpenID Connect or JwtBearerAuthentication middleware. Please check the document below:

[Web applications / APIs protecting resources using .NET Core OpenID Connect or JwtBearerAuthentication middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-signing-key-rollover#owincore)

And here is a code sample to call web API in an ASP.NET Core web application using Azure AD:

[WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIdConnect-DotNet](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore.git)

Comment: Thanks for the code sample, taking a look right now. I'm trying to retrieve JWT signing tokens based on the source code I linked in order to validate JWT tokens sent to my web API issued by MS Graph API though. Do I need to implement `GetSigningCertificates(string metadataAddress)` anyways?

Comment: No, there is no need to using this method for verifying the JWT tokens manually. You can easily to use the **JwtBearerAuthentication** middle-ware to validate the JWT. And this component will handles key rollover automatically for you.

Comment: I fully implemented the middleware but I receive 401 although I provided my JWT token issued by MS Graph: `WWW-Authenticate →Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"` - **Edit:** My TokenValidationParameters configuration - https://pastebin.com/b5Wx5Ryz

Comment: How did you acquire the token? And it is helpful if you can share the **header** of token which you can decode from [this site](https://jwt.io/).

Comment: I'm acquring it through `https://login.microsoftonline.com/(...).onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token` and getting this JSON output in response: https://pastebin.com/BcCwVTT0

Here's the JWT header:
`{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "a3QN0BZS7s4nN-BdrjbF0Y_LdMM",
  "kid": "a3QN0BZS7s4nN-BdrjbF0Y_LdMM"
}`

Comment: Based on the [keys endpoint](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys), the `a3QN0BZS7s4nN-BdrjbF0Y_LdMM` was able to find. Would you mind sharing the code how you protect the web API? Or does the code sample in the post work for you?

Comment: I'm just using the TokenValidationParameters I shared above and Authorize attributes in my controllers

Comment: There is no need to handles key rollover manually, it is more easy to use the JwtBearerAuthentication middleware with one line code to protect the web API like `app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions());`.

Comment: I actually included `app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions());` in `Startup.cs` but I still receive `WWW-Authenticate →Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"` in my header. [Here's](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/04fba164dc459ed13452386ab7af63f6) the JWT Bearer configuration. I guess `TokenValidationParameter` looks fine for me. How can I retrieve the signing key by Microsoft without doing a manual rollover?

Comment: The issue was caused that the **authority** was not set so the OWIN middle ware doesn't know where to retrieve the keys. Please set the authority like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}` and let me know whether it woks for you.

Comment: Hi @FeiXue-MSFT. Thank you for this answer. However, do you happen to know what should be used instead of MetadataSerializer in .NET Core?